# Show and hide element and toggle icon with javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, toggle

When I am clicking on icon I want to toggle class invisible for paragraph and bold for h4.
How can I loop through this? When I am trying I get only the first paragraph.
Also can't change icon on click.

My code:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('i');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
        const h4 = document.querySelector('h4')

        h4.classList.toggle('bold');
        paragraph.classList.toggle('invisible');

        if (btn.classList.contains('hidden')) {
       btn.classList.remove('hidden');
        btn.classList.add('visible');
    }
    else if (btn.classList.contains('visible')) {
        btn.classList.remove('hidden');
        btn.classList.add('visible');
    }
    })
})
```

```
    .bold {
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .invisible {
      display: none;
    }
    i.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;

}
    i.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```
    <div class="question">
      <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
      <p>answear</p>
    </div class="question">
    <div class="question">
      <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
      <p>answear</p>
    </div class="question">
    <div class="question">
      <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
      <p>answear</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is `querySelector()` targets the first match. If you query from `document` you will find first in page and it may not even be in your questions at all if there is any other paragraph or heading content above that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the closest element with class *question* using [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) from which you can find the respective elements:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('i');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    const paragraph = e.target.closest('.question').querySelector('p');
    const h4 = e.target.closest('.question').querySelector('h4')

    h4.classList.toggle('bold');
    paragraph.classList.toggle('invisible');
    
    //if you want the icon to be toggled
    e.target.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-up');
    e.target.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-down');
  })
})
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wESLQ85D6gbsF459vf1CiZ2+rr+CsxRY0RpiF1tLlQpDnAgg6rwdsUF1+Ics2bni" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div class="question">
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div class="question">
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you also recommand how to toggle i class from fas fa-chevron-down to fas fa-chevron-up? - btn.classList.toggle('fas fa-chevron-down') doesn't work

Comment: @IzabelaGórska, you can try `e.target.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-up');; e.target.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-down');`. Updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just toggle a class on the parent question and use class specific rules based on that parent class

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.question i');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const answer = e.target.closest('.question')
    answer.classList.toggle('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
.question.collapsed h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color:red
}

.question.collapsed p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down">Icon</i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down">Icon</i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h4>question<i class="fas fa-chevron-down">Icon</i></h4>
  <p>answear</p>
</div>
```